# How to check if a SQL query is valid for writing with ADO?

Tags: c++, sql, validation, ado

My app has an advanced feature that accepts SQL queries written by the user. The feature should include a "Validate" button to check if the query is valid.

The most simple way I found to do this using ADO is just trying to run the query and catch possible exceptions. But how can I also check if the query enables to add new records or to edit existing ones?

Comment: A little off subject here, but aren't you worried about malicious SQL from the user?  I mean, even if you have an "oops" in the users SQL, wouldn't that be dangerous.  Also, remember Little Bobby Tables, :) - http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: This is meant for a desktop application where each user has his own database files. So any harm done will only affect the user's own data. Plus, this feature is only meant to be used by SQL developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactions, anyone?

```
begin transaction

// Query being validated goes here

rollback transaction
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run the query with "[SET NOEXEC ON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188394.aspx)" .